# Add values in excel column for distinct values in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following layout of column A and B and I need a formula to calculate values in column C:

```
A     B     C
1     10    70
1     20    
1     10    
1     30
2     10    30
2     15   
2     5
3     20    25
3     2
3     3
```

Any ideas or functions which can do this? Basically Sum column B for unique values of column A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A1=A2,"",SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I forgot all about the SUMIF function and was trying to just use some combination of SUM and IF. It was getting too messy.

Comment: Hi @AlastorMoody  We take advantage of the fact that your data is already well-organized..............column **A** appears already sorted.